# how can I access oracle database stored on different machine through a desktop application from other machine

Tags: java, database, oracle, networking, jdbc

I have created a desktop application in java using `jdbc`. I am using `Oracle 10g` express edition. The scene is, I have two PCs connected through LAN.

On one machine I want to install Oracle and put my database there. From second machine I want to access my oracle database using my desktop application. I want to test if my application can connect to database stored on different machine which is connected through LAN.

In `JDBC` connection string I have given the IP of the machine where I have installed oracle database. But I am unable to connect. How can I connect?

Comment: rmi, jni, webservices, ... the sky's the limit

Comment: What errors do you get exactly? More importantly, what did you try to resolve this yourself, once you typed that error code/message in google and browsed through the hits you got?

Comment: @Mat I do not know the exact errors, but this is the scenario which I can tell you: suppose in my application I have `JFrame` containing `textfields` for username and password and login button. Now I want to validate my credentials on oracle database which is stored on other machine which is connected through a LAN with the application's machine.

Comment: @Stultuske so you mean to say I can use rmi, jni, webservices with Swing based desktop applications also. I thought they are only mean for web based technologies. Please confirm me.

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to use them? normally, the business tier has no idea what type of UI there is.

Comment: check firewall and/or other blocking software which may prevent external connection to the computer with Oracle database

Comment: Why don't you know the errors you're getting? Did you give the right port number and service name in your JDBC connection string, is the listener up and on that port and IP (not localhost), is the DB registered, is there a firewall, can the machines see each other at all? There is no way to tell what is wrong from your description.

Comment: Please log your errors and tell what you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Did you download 10G JDBC drivers ?

You can download them from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

And then validate connection availability with this simple program:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class OracleJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("error loading Oracle JDBC driver");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbSERVER:dbPORT:dbSID", "username",
                    "password");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! check stack trace");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection successful!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection successful..");
        }
    }

}
```

Replace "**@dbSERVER:dbPORT:dbSID**" according your infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

Some time back working on similar issue, the culprit was Windows Firewall. Here are the steps that i followed to allow Oracle to be accessed from one machine to another: (I am assuming you are using Windows as your OS)

1. Go to Control Panel > Windows Firewall > Allow a Program or feature through Windows Firewall
2. Click on "Change Settings" and then "Allow another program".
3. Select Oracle or Browse for the same, provide the Port Number is required .
4. Specify if you wan to access it over Domain.

You should be able to access Oracle database across domain.
Hope this helps.